# Scraping/extracting content between two different html tags using python

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this data from a webpage and I want to extract the data between the two headers from WEB TRAFFIC BLOCK LIST to EMAILS. I've been using beautiful soup and can't find related topics. Thanks

```
<h2>WEB TRAFFIC BLOCK LIST</h2>

<p>Indicators are not a block list.&nbsp; If you feel the need to block web traffic, I suggest the following domain and URLs:</p>

<ul>
    <li>hxxp://209.141.49.93/hello.bin</li>
    <li>carder.bit</li>
    <li>gandcrab2pie73et.onion</li>
</ul>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h2>EMAILS</h2>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
content = re.search(
    '<h2>WEB TRAFFIC BLOCK LIST</h2>(.*?)<h2>EMAILS</h2>',
    html,
    re.DOTALL
).group(1)
```

Or with Beautiful Soup, collect the nodes in between the start and end tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
start = soup.find('h2', text='WEB TRAFFIC BLOCK LIST')
end = soup.find('h2', text='EMAILS')
content = ''
item = start.nextSibling

while item != end:
  content += str(item)
  item = item.nextSibling

print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Php Html Parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser). This is the best way to do this.
And if you do it with regex then it should be worst if your page content long data.